# Jenkins: best way to build a project with sub projects

Tags: java, jenkins

We have a project with two subprojects in the same SVN repository.
For example:

```
svn://ip/svn/ trunk/subproject1
svn://ip/svn/ trunk/subproject2
```

The build for project should include results of builds of both subprojects.
To make our build faster, I want to run build of subproject1 only if SVN was changed respectively (in the svn://ip/svn/ trunk/subproject1).  Similarly for subproject2

What is the best way to do it?
Can I do it with a single job?
How should I define build triggers in this case?

Or I need to define 3 jobs:  one for each subproject or one for each project?

Any help will be appreciated!
Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various ways you can achieve this using Jenkins.

1. The [multi-SCM plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin) will allow - as the name suggests - to include multiple source repositories in a single job.
2. You can define `n` jobs which trigger each other (i.e. have a dependency on each other). You can find this under `Build Triggers` > `Build after other projects are built`.
3. There is also the option of a master job controlling the downstream jobs. You'll find this option under `Post-build Actions` > `Build other projects`.

With regard to build triggering, you can use the `poll SCM` option. It's [not the most efficient method](http://kohsuke.org/2011/12/01/polling-must-die-triggering-jenkins-builds-from-a-git-hook/) but your options may be limited with SVN rather than Git.

I just noticed you also mentioned collating results from all builds - you can achieve this either by having a single job or by using the option `aggregate downstream test results` under `Post-build Actions`.

Ultimately, you need to be clear on your build strategy. It sounds to me that you want to ensure that nothing is broken if a change has been made to either sub-project. I'm not sure how well the multi-SCM plugin copes with the concept of polling multiple repositories so you may need to factor that in.

I think I've given you a few options to try out; let me know how you get on.

Comment: I have asked the additional question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122977/jenkins-conditional-trigger-on-the-build-step

Comment: "options may be limited with SVN rather than Git" - despite its other limitations, Subversion, does have a decent system for hooks, and Jenkins can be triggered from the `post-commit` hook on the repo server.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread (18 months) but a few days ago the Jenkins multijob plugin has released a new version that incorporates an option that allows triggering a build only when scm changed since last build:

This is the **Build only if SCM changes**.

There is also an option to force the build regardless of this option.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) available for Jenkins. You can use it to run your sub project builds hierarchically in one main project.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about how to set with SVN, but with **GIT** you can set **Additional Behaviours** on Source Code Management step.

Choose **Polling ignores commits in certain paths**, then set the **Included Regions**. This setting can filter other sub project commits within the same git repository.

Also do setting on **Build Triggers** step, tick **Poll SCM** and leave **Schedule** blank.

If want to set auto deployment, you may need to set **web hook** on git repository side.

Jenkins version is 2.32 and [Jenkins Git plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin)