# Using Jenkins with multiple C projects, ClearCase and shell/batch

Tags: shell, batch-file, jenkins, clearcase, multiple-projects

**BACKGROUND :**

We are working on a few C projects, and the sources are in ClearCase. Each project have his own project ClearCase. My mission consists in putting all of them into Jenkins. There is no Continuous integration so far on this projects.

Some details, but very important :

- The projects MUST be build with Windows AND Linux. Clients wishes.
- The projects are developed on Eclipse, but no Maven, Ant... Only manual build with shell and batch. Already got some makefile to execute, using MinGW and GCC.
- Same for the futures tests, they will be shell and batch scripts. They use real time, so, one test could be 3 minutes long. Average of 15 tests for each projects).

  ---

**Here we are.**
I'm thinking using a free-style project, with 2 slaves (Windows and Unix) for the build. The duration of the test are, now, not really a problem, they should be execute the night. So, maybe using slaves, don't know yet.

What do you guys think ? Got some advice before I get my hand dirty ?

Also, is it possible to have only one Jenkins project, with multiple sub-project with distinct ClearCase sources (and job and sub jub on each of this projects) ? (was looking to MultiJobs, matrix project, [multi-SCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109495/jenkins-best-way-to-build-a-project-with-sub-projects) [Jenkins: best way to build a project with sub projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109495/jenkins-best-way-to-build-a-project-with-sub-projects), but couldn't understand or find the right method)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have edited the question according to Stack Overflow guidelines. Please take the time to get acquainted with them before reverting valuable edit. FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites. Also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115694/6309

Comment: Thanks you. I'll take good note of this for the next topic !

Answer (score 0):

You do not exactly "put a project into Jenkins"

You define Jenkins jobs (start with one per project, you will worry about [pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) later). Those jobs must access the sources of your project in order to populate a Jenkins build workspace and execute whatever you define as a job (in a freestyle job, that can be *any* script in *any* language).

You will need the [ClearCase plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin) (or [ClearCase UCM plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin) of your projects are using UCM): that will allow your job to get the sources of the project.

Start by testing a job directly on the master (that node will be its own slave).
Once it is working, depending on the number of jobs and their frequency, you will scale by adding more slaves.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Indeed, I think I didn't used the right translation/words to explain it. You're right, I intended to use this plugins to connect my (only?) Jenkins project and my many sources on ClearCase. I'll start like you said, step by step.

Comment: @Guildias The plugin is just part of the Jenkins job, used for the Jenkins job to access the source.